# Multibranch job scan fails to discover remote GitHub repo tags

Tags: jenkins, github, github-api, multibranch-pipeline, github-api-v3

I'm using a Multibranch pipeline job to discover branches/tags/PRs and execute certain jobs. I got repos on GitHub and scan is able to discover all but not tags. I get below error. Also, when the **Discover tags** option is disabled in multibranch job configuration, I don't see this error and I miss the build when tags are created.

I tried to create multiple new repos but it did not help.
**Jenkins version: 2.150.1**

```
Getting remote tags...
ERROR: [Sun Jan 06 16:00:21 UTC 2019] Could not fetch branches from source 3f765a8f-ee7f-4c6d-a655-f9ca3b2b25d3
org.kohsuke.github.GHException: Failed to retrieve https://repourl/branch/git/refs/tags
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$PagingIterator.fetch(Requester.java:529)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$PagingIterator.hasNext(Requester.java:494)
at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterator.fetch(PagedIterator.java:44)
at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterator.hasNext(PagedIterator.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource$LazyTags$1$1.hasNext(GitHubSCMSource.java:2222)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieve(GitHubSCMSource.java:1016)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:374)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:284)
at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:634)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:277)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1025)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
[Sun Jan 06 16:00:21 UTC 2019] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.42 sec
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of Pipelines » bl-calibration-orchestrator-v1
org.kohsuke.github.GHException: Failed to retrieve https://repourl/branch/git/refs/tags
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$PagingIterator.fetch(Requester.java:529)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester$PagingIterator.hasNext(Requester.java:494)
at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterator.fetch(PagedIterator.java:44)
at org.kohsuke.github.PagedIterator.hasNext(PagedIterator.java:32)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource$LazyTags$1$1.hasNext(GitHubSCMSource.java:2222)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieve(GitHubSCMSource.java:1016)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:374)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:284)
at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:634)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:277)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1025)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a recent Jenkins issue ([`JENKINS-52397`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52397)) which is still pending:

> ### Org Scan blows up when repository has no tags
>
> Given a GitHub Organization Folder that has the "Discover Tags" behavior; the scan blows up on every repository that doesn't have any tags.
>
> Workaround of adding a single tag confirmed to work

This is linked to the [JENKINS/GitHub Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin), and is still seen in Jenkins 2.152.

From the release notes of the **Jenkins GitHub Branch Source Plugin**:

```
Version 2.4.2
Release date: 2019-01-16
* JENKINS-52397: Org Scan blows up when repository has no tags #191
* INFRA-1934: Stop publishing to jenkinsci/jenkins repo on Docker Hub
```

ref: https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugi/blob/b26aba6136024d4dfaafb9e2c36317128ceb82dd/CHANGELOG.md

It might depend on various factors if you received those plugin already. A Jenkins version of 2.160 (2019-01-16) or higher might or might not be a safe indicator for the fixed version of the plugin being at least available at setup time.

Comment: The workaround did not help, as the repo has tags already in it. Irrespective of tags available or not, the scan fails with the above error.

Comment: Apologize. The workaround helped. I created tags in the repo and the scan was able to pick up the tags. Thanks @VonC

Comment: @prabhu34 Well done! I hope this bug will get fixed soon. What version of the GitHub branch source plugin are you using?

Comment: I use **2.4.1** which I believe is the latest.