# What's causing my Multibranch Pipeline to fail its scan?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a Multibranch pipeline in Jenkins with Bitbucket as the SCM. When I try to "Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now" this is the resulting console log.

```
> git --version # 'git version 2.36.0.windows.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe ls-remote -h -- ssh://git(repo name here).git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: [Mon Jun 27 11:02:32 PDT 2022] Could not fetch branches from source 3387233e-6185-46fa-a65c-0d4072f28149
[Mon Jun 27 11:02:32 PDT 2022] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 7.8 sec
FATAL: Failed to recompute children of MultiBranch Test
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Repository not found
The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:618)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.run(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:602)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource$8.run(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:588)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:394)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.doRetrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:350)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.retrieve(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:588)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource._retrieve(SCMSource.java:373)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetch(SCMSource.java:283)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:641)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:278)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:166)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1032)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Originally, the multibranch was able to scan the repo and find the branches with Jenkinsfiles, but now that no longer works. In the first multibranch test which scanned and created pipelines for branches, when I try to build those branches it fails the build with the same error as above "repository not found".

I have a successful single Pipeline working for the same repository, specifically the develop branch. It is able to build on commits and pull the jenkinsfile from the repo, so it doesnt seem there is an access issue, but that is what the Multibranch pipeline is running into.

--------UPDATE-----------

Randomly, the scan worked. We are not sure what/if any changes prompted the sudden correct performance.

Comment: there is probably some issue around the pub key

Comment: If there was an issue around the pub key wouldn't that issue also present itself in the single pipeline?

Comment: Mulribranch pipeline has the repo credentials section. May be it's misconfigured ? May be other pipeline check it out with http url? There are a lot of options, but bottom line is that the `git` command  executed by multibranch pipeline doesn't know to use the right credentials for checkout

Comment: another option, the url is not correct

Comment: This appears to be a problem specific to Jenkins multibranch pipelines: see the results from https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Could+not+fetch+branches+from+source%22 which includes, e.g., [Multibranch job scan fails to discover remote GitHub repo tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54063516/1256452). (It seems that it is not actually any Git or Bitbucket error at all, it just confuses the plugin which then runs incorrect Git commands and gets errors that it thinks are Git's fault.)